# Graph Error: The property 'Importance' was not found for 'MessageType' item

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch office365 email by using MessageId with Graph API 1.0
and it returns the error message for one messageId.
Though the Same request format works well for other messageId.

API Request:

```
graphClient.users(userId).messages(messageId).buildRequest().get();
```

Response:

> Graph service exception Error code: ErrorInvalidRequest Error message: The property 'Importance' was not found for 'MessageType' item.

Comment: This need to debug from your end , and check what is passing in message_id . also provide the screenshot , if you need any help, thanks

Comment: you can also use try catch block  , catch the exception and ToString , what is the result?